# Why is 'bc' required to build the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, bc

[The Linux kernel minimal building requirements](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/changes.html) specifies that the calculator `bc` is required to build kernel v4.10, the minimal version of the tool being `1.06.95`.

What use is made of `bc` in this context, and why isn't the C language directly used instead of `bc` for these operations?

Comment: What do you mean by using C _directly_? I don't think that using C as a "scripting language" during build is direct or handy.

Comment: @cubuspl42 you could just write the operations in the source, and let the compiler compute it into constants. In reality, what it's used for is a bit too complicated for that.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`bc` is used during the kernel build to generate time constants in header files. You can see it invoked [in `Kbuild`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Kbuild#n35), where it processes [`kernel/time/timeconst.bc`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timeconst.bc) to generate `timeconst.h`.

This *could* be implemented as a C program which is built and run during the build, but it’s easier to use `bc` (which is small and common; in fact it’s part of the set of tools which are mandatory on a POSIX systems — the kernel does expect GNU `bc` though).

`bc` is used here [instead of Perl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=70730bca1331fc50c3caacaea00439de1325bd6e). The commit message suggests that `bc` was used previously, but I can’t find a trace of that; [Perl has been used since 2008](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=bdc807871d58285737d50dc6163d0feb72cb0dc2) (much to [some people’s chagrin](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/669/), although that patch set was never merged).